# Php Date Condition is not going to True

Tags: php

I am using this code for Condtion but I dont know why the condtion is going False

```
<tr
    <?php if ($LevelName['Status'] == 'Yes') { ?>
        style="background:#DCFEB7"
    <?php } ?>
    <?php elseif (strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i')) > strtotime($LevelName['ReportTime'])) { ?>
        style="background:red"
    <?php } ?>
    <?php else { ?>
        style="background:orange"
    <?php } ?>
>
```

I don't know why the backgound color not going to Red

getting this result in condition:

```
(Todat Date)392291420 > (DB Date)1392336360
```

Comment: You can edit your post at any time, so you should edit the post and put the code there, and not inside the comments box. I did it for you now, so you don't need to do anything. Just a hint for next time :-)

Comment: It'd be easier to just use `time()` instead of `strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i'))`

Comment: What is `$LevelName['ReportTime']` variable? Please post it's value. Also, please explain what behavior do you expect from this. Tell us some context etc.